# Как проверить поставлен ли лайк к фото в ВКонтакте

Tags: php, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Не могу никак разобраться. Пробую получить все ид вот таким вот способом, но не работает.

```
$response_2 = file_get_contents("http://api.vk.com/method/likes.getList?type=photo&owner_id=".$owner_id."&item_id=".$item_id."&filter=likes");
$resp_2 = json_decode($response_2, true);
if (in_array($pr_user, $resp_2['response']['users'])) {echo "Лайк к Фото поставлен"; }else{echo "Лайк к Фото НЕ поставлен";}
```

Вернее работает но перед этим показывает вот такую ошибку

```
Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument in Q:\home\localhost\www\vk_servike\vk_service\vklike\vklike.php on line 45
```

Как быть? В чем причина? Помогите кто-нибудь.

Answer (score 1):

Это не ошибка а просто предупреждение. Дословно написано что вы передаете не правильный тип данных во второй аргумент функции.

Comment: А отключить это предупреждение можно как не буть?

Comment: Наверное стоит к ней прислушаться и передать все-таки переменную которую ожидает получить функция. А вообще предупреждения можно отключить, хотя в процессе разработки это обычно не делают. Например так: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645661/turn-off-warnings-and-errors-on-php-mysql

Comment: Сделал так if (@!in_array($pr_user, $resp_2['response']['users'])) и все работает

Comment: Тоже вариант. :)

Comment: Не вариант. Потому, что так гасить ошибки - не профессионально и не правильно. Ошибки надо исправлять. Даже `warning`. Как минимум не собачкой. Потому, что потом будете ожидать какого-то одного поведения от кода, а будет происходить другое. А в коде налеплены такие костыли. Лучше действительно посмотреть что приходит и что отдается функции и и справить на то, что действительно функция ожидает

Answer (score 0):

Если имеется доступ к файлу php.ini то находим в нем параметр error_reporting и выставляем значение:

```
error_reporting = E_ERROR
```

Также предупреждения можно отключить через .htaccess:

```
php_value error_reporting 1
```

Также можно добавить в index.php из корня сайта следующие строки:

```
<?php error_reporting( E_ERROR ); ?>
```